# How to send POST via AJAX when two jquery variables have been defined?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm guessing there's more than one error in this code - but the main thing I'm trying to figure out is how to send the AJAX when a condition is met - which is product and platform variables are defined and not null.  With the following code - I think that line only gets evaluated once.  I don't know if I need to add some type of listener or how this would work with jQuery.  I am entirely new to jQuery.  How do I adjust my code so that a POST is sent when platform and product are defined?  Essentially what I'm wanting is for a user to be able to select a product via checkbox and a platform via another checkbox - and if these conditions are met send a POST with these params and accept the query results on return.

html

```
<H3>Product</H3>
{% for product in products %}
<input type="radio" name="{{ product }}"> {{ product }}
<br>
{% endfor %}


<H3>Platform</H3>
{% for platform in platforms %}
<input type="radio" name="{{ platforms }}"> {{ platforms }}
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-red',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-red',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
  });

  // if product has a checkmark - assign to var
  {% for product in products %}
    $('input['{{ product }}']').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
        var product = $(this).val();
  {% endfor %}

  // if platform has a checkmark - assign to var
  {% for platform in platforms %}
    $('input['{{ platform }}']').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
        var platform = $(this).val();
  {% endfor %}

  // if both vars exist - send POST to /edit_view endpoint
  if (product and platform) {

    {
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"/edit_view/",
             data: {
                    'product': product
                    'platform': platform
                    },
             success: function(){
                 $("#result").data($data);  
             }
        });
        return false;
    });
    }

});
</script>
```

django views

```
def edit_view(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    platforms = Platform.objects.all()
    context = {"products": products, "platforms": platforms}
    return render(request, "edit_view.html", context)

    # handles AJAX - returns queryset data
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        product = request.POST['product']
        platform = request.POST['platform']
        if product and platform:
            product_record = Product.objects.get(name=product)
            platform_record = Platform.objects.get(name=platform)
            records = Records.objects.filter(product=product_record, platform=platform_record)
            return records
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'records': records}))
```

Comment: Agreed, **there's more than one error** (not really errors).  can you tell what's wrong with your code, what you expected?

Comment: Well I'm not really trying to troubleshoot the errors in my code - I'm more specifically trying to figure out what features of jQuery I can use to trigger a POST request when an event happens - in this case when two vars are defined.

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: check my updated answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comments above, to trigger POST request, the way that you do is pretty good, in plus of that you need to send the cross-site request forgery of Django, you don't really need another third framework to handle checkbox/radio, jquery is enough.

First off, your HTMl should be that way:

```
<H3>Product</H3>
{% for product in products %}
<input type="radio" name="product" value="{{ product.id }}"> {{ product }}<br>
{% endfor %}


<H3>Platform</H3>
{% for platform in platforms %}
<input type="radio" name="platform" value="{{ platform.id }}"> {{ platforms }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

And in your js, add a listener to listen when user click on radio, then call the function when the user click on one and `platform` and `product` are defined.

```
$(document).on("click","input[name=product]",function(){
    product = $(this).val();
    platform = $("input[name=platform]:checked").val();
    submitValues(product,platform);
});
$(document).on("click","input[name=platform]",function(){
    platform = $(this).val();
    product = $("input[name=product]:checked").val();
    submitValues(product,platform);
});
```

Here is the function to call

```
function submitValues(product,platform){
    if(product && platform){ // request.POST in case these 2 variables are defined
        ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/edit_view/",
            data: {
                product:product,
                platform:platform,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: function(){
                $("#result").data($data);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT:

either you change your HTML input with the `name`, so you will be able to get your object in your view with `product_record = Product.objects.get(name=product)`

```
<input type="radio" name="product" value="{{ product.name }}"> {{ product }}<br>
<input type="radio" name="platform" value="{{ platform.name }}">
```

Or you leave the HTML input with the ID (`value="{{ platform.id }}"`),then you change the query in your view to:

```
product_record = Product.objects.get(id=product)
platform_record = Platform.objects.get(id=platform)
```

I suggest the second option since ID is unique whereas you may have identical names in your db which will end up with an error.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but what is $("#test") ?  I took this from someone elses code and I'm not sure what this is for or if I need it.

Comment: just the id of the form used in your template, I thought this was your form id, do you have a form in your template?

Comment: I do not have a form in my template no.  I don't want to use a form.

Comment: So go with the first option, the second is when you have a form, or need to generate one with js

Comment: Still, I think the main issue exists - which is that I need to figure out a solution for a POST request to be sent only when these 2 variables are defined - keep in mind there is no submit button.  Essentially I am trying to load data "live" when i click radio buttons..

Comment: I don't really understand your code, that's the problem. i suggest that you edit your code by removing `$("#test").submit(function(event){` this means that you have a form somewhere, and you want to submit it. based on your recent comment, I will edit my answer, before that what is `iCheck`?

Comment: icheck is just a js framework for checkboxes - will update my post

Comment: this doesnt work but i like the idea of submitValues button

Comment: This should work unless your code is not like I thought. Update your question then